# split column into multiple column with different length in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want to split a column in a pandas dataframe into multiple column based on length.
I have a csv file that tells me how many columns i need to split and the length of each column. I will need to refer to this file when i want to do the splitting.

csv file content

```
col |length
id |2
name|5
desc|6
```

example input

```
   value
0  01applefruits
1  02pearsfruits
2  03peachfruits
```

output =
id - length of 2, name - length of 5, desc - length of 6

```
  id   name    desc
0  01  apple  fruits
1  02  pears  fruits
2  03  peach  fruits
```

Above is just an sample. How do i able to have a general code which can split one column into multiple columns in a pandas dataframe?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: `example input` is a dataframe or a csv file?

Comment: its in a text file. and i read it as a df

Comment: This is the real format with `|` as separator? Does it possible to remove whitespaces before `|` in `csv file content`?

Comment: | is for me to show the df structure. updated the question

Comment: Have you looked at Pandas read_fwf?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def Split(x): 
    Id=2
    name=5
    desc=6
    x=x[0]
    return x[:Id],x[Id:Id+name],x[Id+name:]
DF.apply(Split,axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: @Cirralien, thank, likewise. Those -1 without reason are really annoying

Comment: Totally agree. Thanks @Corralien

Answer (score 0):

Assumung the dataframes named `df1` and `df2`:

```
regex = ''.join('(?P<%s>.{%d})' % x
                for x in df1.set_index('col')['length'].to_dict().items())
df2['value'].str.extract(regex)
```

or

```
regex = ''.join('(?P<%s>.{%d})' % (a,b) for (a,b) in df1.values)
df2['value'].str.extract(regex)
```

output:

```
   id   name    desc
0  01  apple  fruits
1  02  pears  fruits
2  03  peach  fruits
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain a bit more on your regex?

Comment: The created regex is `(?P<id>.{2})(?P<name>.{5})(?P<desc>.{6})`, there are named capturing groups, each of which is capturing a fixed number of any characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf) with `widths` parameter.

Assuming the following format of files:

```
>>> %cat 'format.csv'
col,length
id,2
name,5
desc,6

>>> %cat 'data.csv'
value
01applefruits
02pearsfruits
03peachfruits
```

```
fmt = pd.read_csv('format.csv')

df = pd.read_fwf('data.csv', skiprows=1, header=None,
                 names=fmt['col'].tolist(),
                 widths=fmt['length'].tolist())
```

```
>>> df
   id   name    desc
0   1  apple  fruits
1   2  pears  fruits
2   3  peach  fruits
```

Comment: @yuzu. Please don't forget to accept an answer if one of them suits your need. It's important to other users that have a similar problem. It's also important for people who take the time to answer.